# When to pay Zakat al-Fitr

Tags: practical-islam, sunni, hanafi

When are you supposed to pay Zakat al-Fitr?  For example, must it be paid in the mosque you go to pray your Eid pray, or can you pay before than to a different charity of your choice which has a Zakat al-Fitr payment option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer:

> The jurists agree that Zakat-ul-Fitrr is due at the end of Ramadan.
>   They differ, however, about the exact time. Al-Thawri, Ishaq, Malik
>   (in one of two reports), and Al-Shafi`i (in one of his two opinions),
>   are of the opinion that it is due at the sunset of the night of
>   breaking the fast, for this is when the fast of Ramadan ends. However,
>   Al-Layth, the Hanafi school, Al-Shafi`i (in his other opinion), and
>   the second report of Malik say that Zakat-ul-Fitr is due at the start
>   of Fajr (dawn) on the day of `Eid because it is an act of worship
>   connected with`Eid, so the time of its payment should not be before
>   `Eid just as sacrifice on the`Eid of Adha.[12]
>
> These two different views acquire relevance if a baby is born after
>   sunset but before dawn on the day of `Eid; the question then is
>   whether Zakat-ul-Fitr is obligatory for the baby or not. In accordance
>   with the first view, it is not, since the birth took place after the
>   prescribed time, while according to the second view, it is obligatory
>   because the birth took place within the prescribed space of time.[13]

Source: http://www.islamawareness.net/Zakat/fitr003.html